# Commands like \cdot and \delta not working when making equations in MS Word 2018 Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, equations

I have been redirected to this site.
I just installed MS Word 2018 on my new laptop (Mac) the other night and I have run into problems when I make equations. When I type a command into the equation like \cdot or \delta instead of printing a ∂ it just prints \delta. This wasn't a problem on my old laptop running MS Word 2011 (That was also a Mac). Has this feature been removed or changed? can I get it back? it makes writing equations so much faster and easier. 
I have already tried reinstalling the office package but that didn't work.

All help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Microsoft Answer Site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_mac/automatic-replacement-of-symbols-with-equation-in/8158f22c-7d9f-435d-9545-5b799cc892e7), enabling Math Autocorrect will solve this issue. The answer essentially is for Powerpoint 2016, however it applies to Word 2016 as well. Additionally, you also need to set the Math Autocorrect in Word for all other office products.

In short, make sure you have the following settings:

[image]

I have just tested this successfully:

[image]